# Getting basic information when taking over administration of a server

Tags: apache, bash, lamp

This has happened to me a few times and I'd like to save time in the future when running into this situation.

I often either help colleagues out with site deployments or web server configuration. Most times I find myself spending more than what I'd like figuring out:

1. Which apache is running
2. Which httpd.conf is being used
3. Which vhosts file is being used (if any)
4. Where documentroot is pointing to.

#3 and #4 I know I can figure out by looking at httpd.conf. No biggie there. But it's be great if anyone could share a bas command that can help me figure out #1 and #2.

Thanks!

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1:

```
-sh-3.00$ ps auxww|egrep "(http|apache)"
root      8074  0.0  0.3 14236 6696 ?        Ss   Feb11   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
...
-sh-3.00$ rpm -qf /usr/sbin/httpd
httpd-2.0.52-25.ent
-sh-3.00$
```

## 2:

not too sure about the question... if you cannot see conf in the `ps` output then it'll be the default `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Bear in mind that it may include other files, but you can check that by looking at the contents of it and checking for include statements.

Answer (score 0):

`apachectl -v` shows the version of apache your are running. as for "which httpd.conf its running", can you elaborate? do you mean you have multiple httpd.conf ? httpd.conf usually is located in /etc, so you can just do a `find` on /etc eg

```
$ find /etc/ -type f -iname "httpd.conf"
```

Comment: Ah... perfect.

That tells me which httpd.conf file apache is using. I ask because there may be more than one installation and some times it's not easy to figure out which one is actually serving pages. So doing a simple find on httpd.conf may return more than one file.

Now, say there's two installations... how do I figure out whoch one is serving sites? Will a `which apachectl` do?